# Blade @include directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Blade's `@include` directive, allows you to easily include a Blade view from within an existing view. All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view. How can I hide parent values from the included view? I want to only use the variables sent to it or else, use the default variables.

For example, consider the following view. that can access a variable named `$title`

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{$url or URL::previous()}}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
{{$title or 'Save'}}
</a>
```

Comment: I think you can do `@include('view', ['name' => 'Adam'])`

Comment: @Adam Thanks, I know that. I added an example .

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution, but I think I would handle it by putting all of those vars in an array:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{$myData['url'] or URL::previous()}}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
{{$myData['title'] or 'Save'}}
</a>
```

and then including the view: `@include('view', ['myData' => null])`

Note, this is untested.